# Refreshing excel file vb.net

Tags: .net, excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, excel-2013

I have a form created in visual studio 2013 which populates data from form to excel sheet. The sheet is opened when user enters data in the form. What I want is that when user enters data in form and it populates to excel sheet, the file should get refreshed so that everyone can see that. The file is in shared mode.

I tried

```
xlworkbook.refreshall() 'xlworkbook is my excel workbook
```

But it throws an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in Quote.exe
>
> Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

How do I solve this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not understand if the file is opened on the screen or not, but if you want to see the changes to all you need to save the file.

Then you must use the "Save" method and not "RefreshAll"

When you share an Excel file, under advanced options, there is the 'Update changes to save the file', check it if the flag is checked.

Comment: My excel doesn't show the 'Update changes to save the file' options. 
I mean that the users can see the file even when they are entering the data in the form. I saved the file but I since the file is in the shared mode, the users should be able to see which row is full as their data should go in the empty row and not overwrite other person's data